# Postgresql create index concurrently

Tags: postgresql, index

I want to create a concurrently index in postgresql inside a trigger like following code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hour_production_index_partition(partition_name text) RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    -- Ensure we have all the necessary indices in this partition;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS ' || partition_name || '_domain_write_date_idx ON ' || partition_name || ' (fk_domain, write_date)';
    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The problem is that when I execute that statement, postgresql complains sending an error like

> WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25001 ERROR
>   SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY cannot run
>   inside a transaction block   Where: SQL statement "CREATE INDEX
>   CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS
>   hour_production_1_2018_07_01_domain_write_date_idx ON
>   hour_production_1_2018_07_01 (fk_domain, write_date)"

I need to create this index in this way because hour_production table is dinamically break into small parts.

Comment: The `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` statement cannot be inside a trigger - or a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` cannot run inside a transaction, and all functions are transactions, (but ordinary create index can).

Perhaps something like `PG_AGENT` can be leveraged to create the index upon command from your trigger.

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.x/pgagent.html

Alternatively you could do a regular create index when you create the table, an empty table will not be locked for long during a create index.

Comment: PG_AGENT, I will try if this approach is able to solve my problem, Thanks.

The problem with create a regular index is the number of insert that this table has, maybe a hundred of thousands of rows in a day .

Comment: @Joag depending on size of inserted data and business (how often to query new partition table), I think you should consider `create index` when you create the table. Please note that `create index concurrently` would take a long time if your table has a lot activities.